# Remove all span tags from SharePoint 2010 Rich Text Editor (RTE)

Tags: 2010, rich-text

I have users copying and pasting content from a webpage into a SharePoint 2010 RTE. Unbeknownst to them, they are also copying styles that the RTE converts to span tags.  Upon paste, I'd like to automatically remove any/all span tags but keep any remaining markup.  I realize that there will be other related issues but removing the span tags will get me much closer to where I need to be.

I've found a code snippet [here](http://sharepointcustomization.blogspot.ca/2011/09/remove-format-copy-paste-text-editor.html) that removes all markup upon paste.

```
//Disable the RTE paste option. Restricts to "Paste Plain Text" 
function disableMarkupPasteForRTE()
{
 Type.registerNamespace("RTE");
 if (RTE)
 {
  if(RTE.RichTextEditor != null)
  {
   RTE.RichTextEditor.paste = function() { RTE.Cursor.paste(true); }
   // Handle Ctrl+V short cut options in rich text editor
   RTE.Cursor.$3C_0 = true;
  }
 }
}

_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("disableMarkupPasteForRTE");
```

Is anyone able to modify the above code to only remove span tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SharePoint RTE is nothing more than a suped-up ContentEditable div.  The solution is to bind a function onpaste to the editor and then manipulate the html directly.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".ms-rtestate-write").bind('paste', function(e) {
        var text = $(this).html();
        $(this).html(text.replace( /<\s*span.*?>/gi,"").replace( /<\s*\/\s*span\s*.*?>/gi,""));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Sharepoint paste method and modify the html like this:

```
RTE.Cursor.$1u_0--;
RTE.Cursor.$1G_0 = true;
RTE.Cursor.$A2();
RTE.Cursor.$S_0.style.display = '';
var $v_0 = RTE.Cursor.$S_0.contentWindow.document;
var $v_1 = $v_0.body;
var $v_2 = RTE.DomHelper.createRange($v_0);
var $v_3 = new RTE.Range($v_2);
$v_3.moveToElementText($v_1);
$v_3.select();
$v_0.execCommand('paste', false, null);

html = $v_2.htmlText;
//modify the html source

//paste back your new html
$v_2.pasteHTML(newhtml);

RTE.Cursor.updateRangeToCurrentSelectionWithOptions(true);
var $v_4 = RTE.Cursor.get_range();
var $v_5 = $v_4.$1N();
$v_4.deleteContent();
$v_5.select();
RTE.Cursor.$S_0.style.display = 'none';
RTE.Cursor.$2U_0 = true;
RTE.Cursor.$28_0 = true;
RTE.Cursor.$Ei_0();
RTE.Cursor.$59();
RTE.Cursor.$A2();
window.setTimeout(RTE.Cursor.$9w, 0);
if (RTE.Cursor.$1u_0 > 0) {
    window.setTimeout(RTE.Cursor.$5p_0, 10);
}
```